# is there a pipe operator that will unsubscribe from an inner observable of inner observables?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a list of hosts that I want to change during the lifetime of the app. I want the response from each host as soon as it is available. If the host list changes, I don't care about the previous responses from http.get. I want to accumulate all the hosts' responses in a single array and subscribe to it.

The issue I'm having right now is that when the host list changes, the inner observable returned from http.get is not unsubscribed from. I want that host request to be cancelled if that host takes a long time to return and the outermost hosts$ subject has a next value.

A new host list is created with hosts$.next([...])

```
  const accumulator = (acc, val) => [...acc, val]

  hosts$ = new BehaviorSubject(['host1', 'slow2'])

  doer = <T>(): Observable<T> =>
    this.hosts$.pipe( // take an array of hosts
      switchMap(hosts => fromArray(hosts).pipe( // create an array of observable events for each
        mergeMap(host => this.http.get(`http://${host}`).pipe( // hit all the urls at the same time
          catchError(() => []) // on 404 or 500 just give back an empty array
        )),
        startWith([]), // subscribers will see an empty list until the first response
        scan(accumulator), // every response will be accumulated
        shareReplay({
          bufferSize: 1, // allow new subscriptions to get the current value
          refCount: true // but when the last subscription is removed, start over with []
        })
      )) // switch map unsubscribes from the previous host list if the host list changes
    )

  hosts$.subscribe() // here we have the array of responses seen so far as soon
                     // as they are available

  // assuming slow2 is a host that takes forever, and we change the host list...

  hosts$.next(['host3']) // here, the get request to slow2 is not cancelled

  // the output of the observable in doer() is correct,
  //   but the get request should have been cancelled
```

I tried to edit the code above to use a switchMap instead of a mergeMap to allow me to cancel the previous http.get request, but now the only values that come through are the last hosts's get.

As stated in comments, we could add a new observable that represents the "current version of the host list" and use it in the http.get's pipe, and takeUntil the host list changes. Now, every time the host list updates, we send an event on that new observable. This makes me think of a good name for the pipe operator I'm looking for: `obserbale.pipe(takeUntilNext(subject))`

Comment: I am assuming there will be a way to assign new hosts. You can create an another Subject and use takeUntil to unsubscribe. You can emit next item on takeUntil just before assigning new hosts value

Comment: One thing, How are you planning to update hosts   hosts$ = new BehaviorSubject(['host1']) ??

Comment: why are you converting your host array to a stream at all? why not just use forkJoin to get them all at once?

Comment: there's no need for the operator, swithMap already does what you want, you just need to describe your use case a little more clearly

Comment: can you post what the accumulator is doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like this could just be cleaned up like so:

use this utility observable:

```
/*
  takes an array of observables and merges them and accumulates emissions in an array as they arrive
*/
const mergeJoin = <T>(obs$: Array<Observable<T>>): Observable<Array<T>> => {
 return merge(...obs$).pipe(
   scan((acc, val) => [...acc, val], [])
 )
}
```

and do:

```
  private getHost(host) {
    return this.http.get(`http://${host}`).pipe(
      catchError(() => [])  // is the response an array? is that what you want for your error case?
    )
  }

  doer = <T>(): Observable<T> =>
    this.hosts$.pipe(
      switchMap(hosts => mergeJoin(hosts.map(host => this.getHost(host)))),
      startWith([]),
      shareReplay({bufferSize: 1, refCount: true})
    )
```

now you have `doer` written as a function, which is a strange decision for an observable with `shareReplay` attached to it, as it will create a new stream no matter what everytime the function is called, and retriggering the host fetch everytime it's subscribed to, rendering `shareReplay` not as useful. I assume you have your reasons, but if this isn't your goal, just make it a static observable instead of a function.

Comment: to answer your question about why it's a function, doer is parameterized, but not relevant to the question i asked

Comment: ok, then i assume you just want the paramterized version of this shared within a certain context, which is fine, but yea, based on that accumulator, this is all you need to do.

Comment: i will clarify why i want accumulator, and why forkjoin is not correct for my use case "and only want to take action when a response has been received for all"

Comment: please do, as we can modify this slightly if you have other use cases to handle